# Show that $A$ can be inverted when $AB$ = Identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If ***A*** and ***B*** are both *n x n* matrices and ***AB = I***, how would you prove that ***A*** can be inverted?

Comment: What is your definition of an invertible matrix..? Many take this to be the definition.

Comment: invertible implying nonsingular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$AB = I \implies det(AB) = det(I) \implies det(A)det(B) = 1 \implies det(A) \neq 0$. Therefore, $A$ is invertible.